# missing one thing to complete problem set 6 cs50

Tags: cs50

here are the instructions: https://docs.cs50.net/2019/x/psets/6/index.html
I almost finish it but the problem is that the last character of the sentence is a space because of the end=" " and that is th error, but i dont know how to solve it because if i delete the end=" " all the words in the sentence will be togheter because there are not spaces. What should i do?
Here is my code

```
from cs50 import get_string
from sys import argv


def main():
    if len(argv) != 2:
    print("Error")
    exit(1)
wordsbanned = set()
mayuscula = set()
file = open(argv[1], "r")
for line in file:
    wordsbanned.add(line.rstrip("\n"))
    file.close

message = get_string("Enter a message: ")
token = message.split()
for word in wordsbanned:
    x = word.upper()
    mayuscula.add(x)

for t in token:
    if t in wordsbanned or t in mayuscula:
        print(("*" * len(t)), end=" ")
    else:
        print(t, end=" ")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the opposite of `split` as used here `token = message.split()`? It is [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join). What if you stored tokens in a list instead of printing them? Then you could use `join` to turn the result into a string.